# Controlling the length of a loop with real time that can be changed

Tags: c++, loops, time, signal-processing

I have a loop which runs from 0 to 5000 and then resets to 0 and repeats. There is then another loop that creates a 'step' for each time the first loop is reset. There are 16 steps, and once the second loop reaches the end, it resets to 0.

```
    counter = 0;
    pattern = 0;
    tempo = 5000;

    counter++;
        if (counter > tempo) {
            
            counter = 0;
            if(pattern==16) {
                pattern=0;
            }
            
              pattern++;
        }
```

The problem is that the length of time that the loop takes is simply the number '5000' which is not a true time value. If 5000 is increased, the loop takes longer, and if it's decreased, the opposite of course.

I need a way of controlling the length of the tempo loop by a real-world time value in milliseconds/seconds.

This is important as it is a musical program and the 16 step loop needs to be controlled by a time

I have tried using

```
sleep(x)
```

but this did not work and crashed my program upon every attempt.

Comment: This link is for computer graphics and physics simulations but the same principles apply for sound / music generation - https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/   Each frame or time round the loop is your outer loop.  What your program does depends on how long has elapsed since the last time round the outer loop.

Comment: Crashing when you add a `sleep(x);` is symptomatic of bugs (Undefined Behaviour) elsewhere in the program.  We can't do anything about this without a [mcve].

Comment: Ah i see... I kind of get it but unsure of how to implement this into my program. I don't understand how in this example he sets delta time to 1/60th of a second and that is TRULY 1/60th of a second?

Comment: You have only read the 1st section which is basically a statement of the problem.

Comment: Loop and each time round calculate the elapsed time since the last event.  If not enough time has passed continue the loop doing nothing.  When the elapsed time reaches say _"1 beat"_ do the event and reset the elapsed time.

Comment: I understand the process but not how to get the value of time in seconds it has taken for the event to have passed

Comment: [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono)

Comment: [Busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) is generally a waste of CPU resources, unless you only want to wait for very short time periods (less than 10 microseconds). Therefore, it would probably be best to call [`nanosleep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html), [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) or [`std::this_thread::sleep_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) a single time, instead of using a loop.

Comment: isn't this better handled by the OS?  What OS is this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but is, as expected, not super accurate ("date; time ./a.out; date" were all entered at once):

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat timer.cpp
// to compile: "g++ -std=c++11 helloWorld.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int counter = 1;
    int pattern = 0;
    int tempo = 4;
    int tester = 0;
    int patternLimit = 6;

    while(1){
        usleep(1000000);
        cout << "w" << endl;
        if(counter == tempo) {
            cout << "x" << endl;
            counter = 0;
            pattern++;
        }
        if(pattern == patternLimit) {
            cout << "y to break" << endl;
            pattern=0;
            //continue;
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
Mac_3.2.57$g++ -std=c++11 timer.cpp
Mac_3.2.57$date
Mon Jan 23 10:35:48 EST 2023
Mac_3.2.57$time ./a.out
w
w
w
w
x
w
w
w
w
x
w
w
w
w
x
w
w
w
w
x
w
w
w
w
x
w
w
w
w
x
y to break

real    0m24.077s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.004s
Mac_3.2.57$date
Mon Jan 23 10:36:12 EST 2023
Mac_3.2.57$
```